# Cutting the top two lines after every six lines from a file containing 180 lines

Tags: unix, sed, cut

I want to extract the top two lines from a file (a set of 180 lines) such that, if I group the file in to sets of 6-6 lines, I get the first two lines as my output. So I should be able to get the 1st,2nd followed by 7th,8th and so on. I tried using sed for this but not getting the desired output.

Could some one please suggest the logic to be implemented in here

My requirement is to make some modifications on the first two lines (like removing certain characters), for every set of 6 lines.

Example:

```
This is line command 1 for my configuration
This is line command 2 for my configuration
This is line command 3 for my configuration
This is line command 4 for my configuration
This is line command 5 for my configuration
This is line command 6 for my configuration
```

The output I want is:

```
This is line command 1
This is line command 2 
This is line command 3 for my configuration
This is line command 4 for my configuration
This is line command 5 for my configuration
This is line command 6 for my configuration
```

This has to repeat for every 6 commands out of 180 commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the modulus of the division of the line number / 6. If it is 1 or 2, then print the line. Otherwise, do not.

```
awk 'NR%6==1 || NR%6==2' file
```

`NR` stands for number of record, which in this case is "number of line" because the default record is a line. `||` stands for "or". Finally, it is not needed to write any `print`, because it is the default behaviour of `awk`.

#### Example:

```
$ seq 60 | awk 'NR%6==1 || NR%6==2'
1
2
7
8
13
14
19
20
25
26
31
32
37
38
43
44
49
50
55
56
```

---

Based on your update, this can make it:

```
$ awk 'NR%6==1 || NR%6==2 {$6=$7=$8=$9} 1' file
This is line command 1   
This is line command 2   
This is line command 3 for my configuration
This is line command 4 for my configuration
This is line command 5 for my configuration
This is line command 6 for my configuration
This is line command 7   
This is line command 8   
This is line command 9 for my configuration
This is line command 10 for my configuration
This is line command 11 for my configuration
This is line command 12 for my configuration
This is line command 13   
This is line command 14   
This is line command 15 for my configuration
This is line command 16 for my configuration
This is line command 17 for my configuration
This is line command 18 for my configuration
This is line command 19   
This is line command 20   
This is line command 21 for my configuration
This is line command 22 for my configuration
This is line command 23 for my configuration
This is line command 24 for my configuration
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this solution, Can I also make some modifications on the remaining 4 lines from each set? How can I resist the first two lines from getting impacted?

Comment: @awrit what do you mean? So the output would be `7, 8...`?

Comment: Ohk, I have a set of 180 commands to configure 180 links. Now, my actual requirement was to make changes on the 1st and 2nd command, which recursively repeats the same after 6 commands.     So I wanted to know how can I do this operation.

Comment: Yes you can.  `awk 'NR%6==1 || NR%6==2 {do some} !(NR%6==1 || NR%6==2) {do some other}'`

Comment: Exatly Jotne, or even `awk 'NR%6==1 || NR%6==2 {do some; next} {do some other}'`

Comment: @awrit it is still not clear to me, can you update your question with proper input and desired output?

Comment: @Fedorqui: For eg. I have following commands:  "add signaling ss7 link  destination-point-code-name iSlNnRAN5 id 125 own-point-code-name iSlOIWF1 slc 0 node-name /CLA-0  mtp2-link-profile ITU_T mtp2-timer-profile ITU_T number-of-time-slots 1 pcm-id 1 time-slot 1 spmc-link no"
  Now there are 180 such consecutive commands. I want this o/p: "add signaling ss7 link  destination-point-code-name iSlNnRAN5 id 125 own-point-code-name iSlOIWF1 slc 0" for the first two commands in a set of 6.    This looks quite messy but this is what I am looking for.

Comment: @awrit please update your initial post (the question) so it is easier to read than in the comments.

Comment: @fedorqui: I have modified my question. Please suggest what should be my approach.

Answer (score 3):

You already have an answer from @fedorqui using `awk`.  Here is an approach using `sed`.

```
sed -n '1~6,2~6p' inputfile

# Example
$ seq 60 | sed -n '1~6,2~6p' 
1
2
7
8
13
14
19
20
25
26
31
32
37
38
43
44
49
50
55
56
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this solution, Can I also make some modifications on the remaining 4 lines from each set? How can I resist the first two lines from getting impacted?